# Differentiate between slide and touch

Tags: android

How can i differentiate between slide and touch in android. In my app, i need to provide the slide functionality from my home screen. There are some icons also on the home screen. When I slide from the home screen and if my touch area is any icon, then its calling the 'onItemClickListener' first and then the 'onTouchEvent'. I want that in case of slide it should call only the 'onTouchEvent' and not 'onItemClickListener'. Pls help..
 Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a gesture recognizer. Take a look at the [GestureDetector](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/GestureDetector.html) class and also [this article](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/gestures.html).

Answer (score 1):

Your activity must implement `GestureDetector.OnGestureListener`.  Use the method `onFling` to handle the slide movement. To handle the touch event, you just need to override the `onTouch` method.